# Need Help Understanding A Sentence Using "In Part"

Tags: vocabulary, sentence

I'm reading a book and I've encountered a sentence:-

> The state of a process is defined in part by the current activity of
>   that process.

I can't understand what's the point of using the words "in part". Do the above sentence means the same as:-

> The state of a process is defined by the current activity of that
>   process.

Comment: *in part* = *partially*. Current activity is only one of many elements which contribute to the state of a process.

Comment: This is [general reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-part?q=in+part), I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they do not mean the same thing.

The first sentence draws attention to the fact that it is not only the current activity of a process which defines its state but also other circumstances.

As an example you could say

> My mood is defined in part by what I had for dinner.

But it would be very strange if you claimed

> My mood is defined by what I had for dinner.

The latter would mean is that no matter what else happened in your life you mood is only conditional on what you ate, whereas the first says that what you ate has an effect on your mood.